# Nodejs Mongodb update multiple collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In mongodb have two collections for now Event and Packages. So basically the model looks like this

Event Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

const EventSchema = new Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  eventname: {
    type: String,
    required : true,
  },
  eventdesc: {
    type: String,
    required : true,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Event', EventSchema);
```

Package Model looks like this

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

const PackageSchema = new Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  eventpackages: {
    type: Object,
    required : false,
  },
  event: { 
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    ref: 'Event'
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Package', PackageSchema);
```

Here I am trying to update an event so when the event will be updated the packages will be updated also. So in nodejs I have done like this

```
    var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


/* UPDATE EVENT */
router.put('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  upload(req, res, function(err) {
    let EventData = {
      eventname       : req.body.eventname,
      eventdesc       : req.body.eventdesc, 
    }

    let EventPackages = {
      eventpackages : req.body.sections,
    }
    Event.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, EventData, function (err, post) {
      if (err) return next(err);

      Package.findAndModify({
        query: { event: req.params.id },
        update: { $inc: { EventPackages } },
        new: true, 
        upsert: true 
      })
        res.json(post);
    });
  });
});



module.exports = router;
```

But its not working at all. If I will deleted the codes for package update it will work for events.

So can someone tell me how to make this work so that I can update multiple collections at a time.

Comment: What does not work? You get any errors or updates are not done?

Comment: Not sure if Mongoose supports `findAndModify`, I know it supports this through the helpers `findOneAndUpdate` and `findByIdAndUpdate`. Perhaps you meant to invoke the underlying collection function directly as `Package.collection.findAndModify(...)`?

Comment: You're using increament operator on eventpackages, which is of type of object? Still unclear on what you want to do but this is one error.

use $set instead of $inc

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```
    var query = {
              'event': req.params.id
              };
    var dataToUpdate = {
       $set: {
          ///
       }
};
Package.updateMany(query, datatoUpdate, function(err, result) {
       if (err) return handleError(err);

       return Promise.resolve(result);
});
```