# Angular 5 add product by quantity and show the total price with max limit

Tags: javascript, angular

In angular 5 I am creating an application where user can select quantity of products and once they are done the product price with the quantity would be shown in the total price. But here is something like quantity limit.  So lets say a product has max quantity limit 4 then user can add upto 4 quantity, not more than 4. If he does that then he will get some message.

Here is my code so far

`app.component.html` looks like this

```
<table class="table event-package-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="ticket-type"><h6>Ticket Type</h6></th>
      <th class="price"><h6>Price</h6></th>
      <th class="quantity"><h6>Quantity</h6></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let package of packagesArray">
      <td>{{package.tickettype}}</td>
      <td>{{package.price}}</td>
      <td>
        <div class="container quantity-spinner-wrap">
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="input-group number-spinner">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" data-dir="dwn">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">-</span>
                </button>
              </span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" value="0">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" data-dir="up" (click)="addEventPackages(package.price,package.limit)" >
                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">+</span>
                </button>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<div>Total Price: {{Price}}</div>
```

and `app.component.ts` looks like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  eventPackagePrice = [];
  Price : number ;
  packagesArray = [
    {
      'tickettype': 'general', 'price' : 99, 'limit' : 4,
    },
    {
      'tickettype': 'vip', 'price' : 299, 'limit' : 2
    },
    {
      'tickettype': 'staff', 'price' : 79, 'limit' : 4
    },
    {
      'tickettype': 'service', 'price' : 109, 'limit' : 2
    }
  ]

  addEventPackages($price,$packageLimit) {
    this.eventPackagePrice.push($price);
    this.addPrice(this.eventPackagePrice);
  }

  addPrice($array) {
    let sum = 0;
     for (let i = 0; i < $array.length; i++){
      sum += $array[i];
   }
   this.Price = sum;
  }
}
```

Also there in the html you can see the quantity box. I had used jQuery to make quantity +1 and make -1. But I want to do that in angular. So can someone tell me how to do them? Any suggestions or advice will be really appreciable.

Here is the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3rwkvf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See you will need three functions to make it work, One to increase quantity, one to decrease and one to count price. This is where you will show your errors as well.

Also you will need one more variable to hold quantity of each item.

So for that I have made your array like this

```
 packagesArray = [
{
  'tickettype': 'general', 'price' : 99, 'limit' : 4,quantity : 0
},
{
  'tickettype': 'vip', 'price' : 299, 'limit' : 2,quantity : 0
},
{
  'tickettype': 'staff', 'price' : 79, 'limit' : 4,quantity : 0
},
{
  'tickettype': 'service', 'price' : 109, 'limit' : 2,quantity : 0
}]
```

Now the functions will be like

```
    increase_quantity(temp_package){
    if(temp_package.limit == temp_package.quantity){
      return alert("Can't add more")
    }else{
      temp_package.quantity++
      this.Price += temp_package.price
    }
  }

  decrease_quantity(temp_package){
      if(temp_package.quantity == 0){
        return alert("can't be in minus")
      }
      temp_package.quantity--
      this.Price -= temp_package.price
  }
  countPrice(){
     this.Price = 0;
      for(let p of this.packagesArray){
        this.Price += p.price*p.quantity
      }
  }
```

And finally the calls would be

```
<tr *ngFor="let package of packagesArray">
  <td>{{package.tickettype}}</td>
  <td>{{package.price}}</td>
  <td>
    <div class="container quantity-spinner-wrap">
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="input-group number-spinner">
                      <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dir="dwn" (click)="decrease_quantity(package)">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">-</span>
                        </button>
                      </span>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" [(ngModel)]="package.quantity" (change)="countPrice(package)">
                      <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dir="up" (click)="increase_quantity(package)" >
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">+</span>
                        </button>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

As you can see I have assigned quantity to the variable in object itself, which we are using to check if quantity should be increased or decreased or error should be thrown.

attaching a working [Plunker](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p3zxop?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) just in case.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But as the data are coming from database how can I make the quantity as 0? Is there any tweaks where I can get the quantity and check?

Comment: Yes, You can get the data of quantity from database via JSON and assign that to the quantity in our array of objects quantity field

Comment: Actually I don't have any field like quantity in the database for now. So without adding quantity in the database should I do something so that it would not look for quantity.

Comment: If you want quantity to be other than 0, It has to come from database.. or any persistant storage.

Comment: can you answer my this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49520898/angular5-create-form-by-getting-the-field-name-and-options-from-the-database