# Angular5 create form by getting the field name and options from the database

Tags: javascript, angular

In angular 5 I have the data which is coming from the database like this

```
data = [
{type: 'radio', label: 'gender', options: 'male,female', required: 'yes' }
{type: 'input', label: 'first name', options: '' }
{type: 'select', label: 'country', options: 'india,pak,sri lanka' }
]
```

I want to create a from using those data. I have decided to make it as like a formarray so that I can easily save the values into the database easily with validation. So for that I have made my code like this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-registration-checkout',
  templateUrl: './registration-checkout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registration-checkout.component.css']
})

export class RegistrationCheckoutComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private formBuilder : FormBuilder,
    ) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.checkOutService.getExtraFields().subscribe( response => {
      this.fields = (response['fields']);
      console.log(this.fields); //Here I am getting the data in json format what I have explained above
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

initSection() {
    return new FormGroup({
        //here I have to make something with the data
    });
}

addSection() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.form.get('sections');
    control.push(this.initSection());
  }

 getSections(form) {
    return form.controls.sections.controls;
  }
```

But I don't know how can I use those data in initSection so that it would create the form easily with validation functionality.
  So can someone tell me how to do that? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

**Updated Code**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-registration-checkout',
  templateUrl: './registration-checkout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registration-checkout.component.css']
})

export class RegistrationCheckoutComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private formBuilder : FormBuilder,
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.eventService.getEvent(eventid).subscribe( response => {
            this.Data = eval(response.fields);
            console.log(this.Data);
        });

        let plainObject = {}
        this.Data.map((field)=>{
            plainObject[field.label] = new FormControl('')
        });

        this.dynamicForm = this.formBuilder.group(plainObject)
    }
}
```

My template looks like this

```
<div class="field" *ngFor="let field of Data ">
  <div class="form-group col-2" *ngIf="field.type ==='input'">
    <label for="{{field.label}}">{{field.label}}</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="First Name" formControlName="{{field.label}}">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-2" *ngIf='field.type=="radio"'>
    <label for="{{field.label}}">{{field.label}}</label>
    <input type="radio" name="{{field.label}}">
  </div> 
  <div class="form-group col-2" *ngIf="field.type ==='select'">
    <label for="{{field.label}}">{{field.label}}</label>
        <select class="" formControlName="{{field.label}}" >
        <option *ngFor="let option of field.options.split(',')" [value]="option">{{ option }}</option>
      </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-2" *ngIf="field.type ==='radio'">
    <label for="{{field.label}}">{{field.label}}</label>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let option of field.options.split(',')">
        <input type="radio" [name]="option"> {{ option }}
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I am using the values what I have got from service is not working. Might be the service is getting data after some time and in that mean time the form has initialised.

Comment: the solution you need is this article https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

Comment: can you share some code because I am just a newbie in angular

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/angular/oeqynjqypbx

Comment: @Ricardo thanks for the link. But can you share something with my data? I really need it.

Answer (score 0):

the concept your are looking for is dynamic forms, is a way to handle and build forms from data that are you receiving from the backend

let say you want to build a reactive form and the only data you have is this array

```
data = [
{type: 'radio', label: 'gender', options: 'male,female', required: 'yes' }
{type: 'input', label: 'first name', options: '' }
{type: 'select', label: 'country', options: 'india,pak,sri lanka' }
]
```

in the view you dont now the number of fields and the type thats why you need to loop over the array of fields and construct the template dyamically

```
<form class="form-group" [formGroup]="dynamicForm">
   <div class="field" *ngFor="let field of data">
     <input type="{{field.type}}" [formControlName]="field.label">
     // here is where the magic happens , based on the kind of field you 
     // need to create your custom types populated with specific values 
   </div>
 </form>
```

I recommend you create custom components that implements `ControlValueAccessor` interface (the interface that help you create custom reactive forms) 
and pass the object `field` to this dynamic form input

so how to build the reactive form `dynamicForm`

the idea is the same as the template:

a loop over all the field and set the name of the object and declare the form control values, use the FormBuilder class to help you construct the form

let assume `field.label` is a id of your form field

```
private fb: FormBuilder // import this on the constructor
let plainObject = {}
data.map((field)=>{
  plainObject[field.label] = this.fb.control(field.value,[/**include here the validators*/])
})
this.dynamicForm = this.fb.group(plainObject)
```

`field.value` is a example I use to set up the default value to the form, I don't now your real structure of your data

this is a approach you can follow

**UPDATE TO NEW CODE**

you can start improving the code on ngOnInit 
you only going to receive your data once the response from the backend has arrive so your code should look like this

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.eventService.getEvent(eventid).subscribe( response => {
        this.Data = eval(response.fields);
        let plainObject = {}
        this.Data.map((field)=>{
           plainObject[field.label] = new FormControl('')
        });

        this.dynamicForm = this.formBuilder.group(plainObject)
    });


}
```

otherwise the dynamic form never is going to be initialized

Comment: actually when I am checking for field inside ngfor loop in the template it is showing blank. Also in the component 
this.fb.control(field.value,'') I am using this.fb.control(field.label,'') as there is no field like value in the data

Comment: you need to have a way to identify your field and make it  unique, about field.value,  that was a example how to pass the default value to your form, something you will need to manage at some point

Comment: I am still struggling with this. Can you help me ?

Comment: Actually when I am using the hardcoded values for data it is somehow working. but when I am getting the data from service it is showing error.

I think the service is showing data after some time but before that the form is initialsed and thats why it is showing error

Comment: check my updated question with the code what I have done so far inside Updated Code heading