# Angular Form Array, first Index always null

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-reactive-forms

Please assist, i am trying to view data from the component to the view, using angular form array. the following solution: [Angular 5 FormArray get data from database and show rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48803725/angular-5-formarray-get-data-from-database-and-show-rows?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) .  helped me but now im experiencing a problem where the first index of the form array is always null and im recieving the following errors :

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: '[object Object] -> 0'
at _throwError (forms.js:2432)
at setUpFormContainer (forms.js:2405)
at FormGroupDirective.addFormGroup (forms.js:6691)
at FormGroupName.AbstractFormGroupDirective.ngOnInit (forms.js:2568) 
...

Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] 
...
```

in my ngOnInit i only have the following :

```
this.SectionForm= this.formBuilder.group({
  sectionData: this.formBuilder.array([this.buildDevelopmentSector()])
});

this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(res =>
  // get data and push the data to a formArray called sectionDataArray
  this.GetDataFromApi(res.requestId)
);
```

the view has the following part :

```
  <div [formGroup] ="SectionForm">
    <div [formArrayName]="sectionDataArray">
      <div *ngFor="let section of sectionDataArray.controls ; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
          ...
          ...
          ...
        </div>
```

Looking at the logs i see the following :

```
  0:
     amount:""
     percentage:""
     name:""
     quantity:""
     __proto__:Object 

  1:
     amount:1200000
     percentage:23
     name: "Repo"
     quantity:20000
     __proto__:Object

  length:2
     __proto__:Array(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You backing object has

```
sectionData: this.formBuilder.array([this.buildDevelopmentSector()])
```

so its `sectionData` but you are reffering to `sectionDataArray` here

```
<div [formArrayName]="sectionDataArray">
```

change it to `sectionData`

Comment: and remove square brackets from `[formArrayName]`

Comment: Or change to `[formArrayName]='sectionData'"` :)

Comment: or make a property on component `sectionData:string = 'sectionData'` :)

Comment: Manage to sort the error, the reason i was getting the error was because   i was not calling or  Initializing the `sectionDataArray` onInit. Thank you.

Comment: Well basicly thas what I wrote - u were reffering to undefined property.

Comment: Yes, i was getting the following error  `Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]` because `sectionDataArray` was initialized on method call not on NgOnInit.